# Workflow throws error 'GetVersionInfo' when file is no longer present

Tags: powershell, workflow

Consider this scenario:

```
$Error.Clear()

Workflow Test-Workflow {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [Array]$File
    )
    'Workflow executed'
}

$File = New-Item $env:TEMP\test.txt -ItemType File -Force

$Object = [PSCustomObject]@{
    File = $File
    Test = 'Stuff'
}

Test-Workflow -File $Object 
$Error
```

All executed fine and there are no errors. Now once the file is removed the workflow no longer executes without errors:

```
$Error.Clear()
Remove-Item $File
Test-Workflow -File $Object 
$Error
```

The following error is reported twice:

```
Exception calling "GetVersionInfo" with "1" argument(s): "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Temp\3\test.txt"
At line:1 char:1
+ [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($this.FullName)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundExceptio
```

Is this normal behavior? How can this be avoided? Because we would like to archive the file before we execute the workflow. Or am I missing something super obvious here regarding workflow specifics?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is happening is that `$object` stores a reference to the file you created. You have then deleted the file which is referenced. This is why you have a `FileNotFoundException`

```
#Delete your file
Remove-Item $File
#Try to pass reference to deleted file to Workflow, when it looks it finds no file and fails 
Test-Workflow -File $Object
```

Because of this failing is normal behaviour. What you could do is create a temporary copy of the file before archiving and delete the temp file after working on it. Otherwise I think you would have to load the contents of the file into memory and only operate on the object in memory and make sure nothing looks for your deleted file.

Comment: So when I do the same with an `Advanced function` in PowerShell there's no error but with a `Workflow` there is. Really strange that the `Workflow` wants to check the existence of the file while that is not required at all. Thanks for the help anyhow.

Comment: I fixed it fairly simple by selecting the properties I need upfront, like this `File = $F | Select-Object Name, BaseName, FullName`

Comment: I do find Powershell a bit more obscure when it comes to behind-the-scenes actions.  The link below outlines the limitations of variables in Workflows among other things. I think losing the file object in memory and needing the actual file still to be present has something to do with the fact that workflows are not actually powershell but code translated into something else by Powershell. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn151046.aspx